# for accessible website design, table or not table?

Tags: accessibility

I have to create a web site. The website is simple, only a page to make a search box and a page to show the results. But the results will give a lot of information and I have to structure the data.

Actually, I'm in the design stage and I have to choose if I show the results of the search with a table or not. I hate table, it's "uggly", not ergonomic, not convenient. But my team use to read this information in excel table form and they are afraid to change this way.

If I want my website to be accessible, is a table is a good choice or should I follow my preference and structure it another way?

Comment: You need to share a quick example of what the data looks like for us to give you a definitive answer but judging by the fact this data gets copied to excel it should be a table as it is tabular data. Tables don't have to be ugly, you have a lot of styling options nowadays so not sure what you mean there? Do you want to add an example of the data that needs to be displayed (just a couple of rows worth) so we can help further.

Comment: What HTML elements would you use if not a table?

Comment: It would depend on the data but it might be more appropriate to have an unordered list and just text nodes such as `<p>` and `<span>` in it, or it might be very complex data so we would use headings, and some `aria` to set associations etc. That is why it is impossible to answer this question properly without seeing the data structure as it may not be suited to be tabular data from a semantics perspective (although it more than likely would be!).

Answer (score 4):

It depends on whether you have genuine [tabular data](https://www.w3.org/TR/tabular-data-model/#dfn-tabular-data:%7E:text=Tabular%20data%20is%20data%20that%20is,tabular%20data%20from%20other%20line%2Doriented%20formats.) or if you're just using the table to control layout and formatting.

If your data requires column headers and/or row headers to make sense, then it's likely tabular data and should go in a [properly marked-up](https://webaim.org/techniques/tables/data#headers) `<table>` element.

Using [tables for layout](https://webaim.org/techniques/tables/#uses) isn't explicitly bad, assuming that you don't include markup that indicates data relationships (e.g. `<th>` element, `scope` or `header` attributes, etc.), but there are better options now, like [CSS-grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) or [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).